# Is there a way of removing pixels in an image that have less than two neighbors using opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, noise-reduction

After performing a bunch of preprocessing steps, I have this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXhuv.jpg). I'd like to remove the tiny islands of noise from within the image. What I've noticed is that these noisy pixels are directly connected to less than two pixels in their neighborhood. Is there a way of extracting just the logo and the letters "PUSH TO OPEN" without the noisy pixels?

I've already tried basic morphological operations such as erosion ([cv2.erode](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html#erosion)) and [opening](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html#opening) to no avail.

I apologize if I've not made any part of my question clear as I'm a beginner at opencv. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure, but it looks like [salt-and-pepper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt-and-pepper_noise) noise. You can remove it using smoothing filter such as [median filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_filter) in your preprocessing step. Oh since you're new to OpenCV, you might want to look at [OpenCV tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/gausian_median_blur_bilateral_filter/gausian_median_blur_bilateral_filter.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I cleaned the image out with the median filter as you had mentioned and it worked!